# Ms Excel IF ISNUMBER SEARCH for multiple text using AND or OR operator

Tags: excel

This is my excel data

[image]

As you can see in `B2`, this formula only search for the first text it found and will ignore the rest.

What I'm trying to accomplish is if 2 or more different texts are found like `B2`, is it possible to print another message ... let say `Apple & Banana found`

[image]

This is my original excel formula for your reference:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A2)),"Apple",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",A2)),"Banana",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cher",A2)),"Cherries",
"Other")))
```

Comment: Formula approach may not be feasible if you have many such items (fruit names) to check and you expect the list to grow. A VBA UDF will help. On the other hand, if the list is specific (e.g. 3,4 items like you've shown) to check then your formula with little tweak will work.

Comment: Thanks @ShrivallabhaRedij. I would appreciate if you could show an example how to accomplish that little tweak

Comment: I have posted tweaked formula. See if it helps.

Comment: Yeah it works! Many thanks @ShrivallabhaRedij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if following formula tweak helps you:

`=TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A2)),"Apple "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",A2)),"Banana "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cher",A2)),"Cherries "," "),
IF(SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"apple","banana","cher"},A2,1)))+0)=0,"Other "," ")))&" found"`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and tried and thought hmmm why don't I simply add a SUBSTITUTE function...and it worked ;o)

Just in case there is someone out there looking for this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A2)),"Apple "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",A2)),"Banana "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cher",A2)),"Cherries "," "),
IF(SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"apple","banana","cher"},A2,1)))+0)=0,"Other "," "))),"Apple Banana","Both")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal :

You create a Table with your KeyWord and Result in two columns 
(columns K for KeyWord and L for Result).

You change your formula like this

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K2,A2)),L2, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K3,A2)),L3, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K4,A2)),L4, "Other")))
```

After that, is more easy to add new KeyWord, to change the order if you want to prioritize a KeyWord more than an other.

You can't use more than 63 KeyWords, but you can create a second formula from 64 to 126.